# Extracting values along a row, column or diagonal of a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, slice

I have a 2 dimensional matrix and I want to get the data along a particular line. Similar to what 'Slice' does to a 3D matrix. Is there a a way to do a similar thing on a 2D matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting all values of a column or a line:

```
>> M = magic(4)
M =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
>> particular_row = 3;
>> M(particular_row,:)
ans =
     9     7     6    12
>> particular_column = 2;
>> M(:,particular_column)
ans =
     2
    11
     7
    14
```

---

Extracting values along a diagonal:

> What if I want to get the data along any direction say along a line joining matrix index (1,1) to (4,4) of a 5x5 matrix?

I'd use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) and the [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function for this task. Demo:

`(1,1)` to `(4,4)`:

```
>> M = magic(5)
M =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
>> M(sub2ind(size(M), 1:4, 1:4))
ans =
    17     5    13    21
```

Another example: `(1,2)` to `(3,4)`:

```
M(sub2ind(size(M), 1:3, 2:4))
ans =
    24     7    20
```

Comment: This is fine, but what if I want to get the data along any direction say along a line joining matrix index (1,1) to (5,4) of a 5x5 matrix ?

Comment: @Sagar I cannot see a straight line between (1,1) and (5,4). Do you mean (1,1) to (4,4) or (1,1) to (5,5) or (2,1) to (5,4)?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant it to be (4,4)